# Mongoose Error when using findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting **Query was already executed** error when using **findByIdAndUpdate** in mongoose to update a todo list.

### Console

```bash
/Users/ariful/dev/todo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:21
      const err = new MongooseError('Query was already executed: ' + str);
                  ^

MongooseError: Query was already executed: Todo.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectId("62eb7849edd528678...
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (/Users/ariful/dev/learn/todo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:21:19)
    at /Users/ariful/dev/learn/todo/node_modules/kareem/index.js:426:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  originalStack: 'Error\n' +
    '    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (/Users/ariful/dev/learn/todo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:25:28)\n' +
    '    at /Users/ariful/dev/learn/todo/node_modules/kareem/index.js:426:25\n' +
    '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)'
}
```

### My Code:

### Todo Controller

```js
// PUT TODO
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {

    // Update a todo
    const result = await Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
            $set: {
                status: "active",
            },
        },
        {
            new: true, // for getting updated result
        },
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: "Opps! - can't create todo some error happend!"
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Todo updated sucessful!"
                });
            }
        }
    )
    console.log(result);
})
```

**After executing put request the server crashes but the value updated in the database.**

Comment: Don't mix promises and callbacks.

Comment: You're mixing async/await syntax which callback. Pick only one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using async await style, so put the code inside `try/catch` block.
This should work without an error

```
try {
 const result = await Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
            $set: {
                status: "active",
            },
        })

 res.status(200).json({ message: "Todo updated sucessful!"});
  } catch (error) {
     res.status(500).json({
                    error: "Opps! - can't create todo some error happend!"
                })
  }
```

Comment: @Ariful this should have fixed the problem. If not, then there's some context missing from your question (for instance the use of Mongoose middleware, or code that you left out).

Comment: Thanks for feedback. It worked :) I mixed promises and callbacks.